# zabbix 1.8 api get event information

Tags: api, zabbix

How to get from api information shown in the [picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X5IxY.jpg)?

I have the connection to api, and I couldn't find in api documentation, the method to get this event details.
thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You need the `event.get` method. See this page in the Zabbix manual: https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/3.0/manual/api/reference/event/get

Specifically, you probably need the second example, "Retrieving events by time period".

If you want to get trigger names, use the `selectRelatedObject` flag. As the default `source` is triggers, you should not get discovery, internal and auto-registration events.

If you really use the old 1.8 version, the flag for trigger names is `select_triggers` - see https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/1.8/api/event/get .

Comment: Hello, thanks but I need to get some description of event and message, `event.get` return event id and etc, without necessary infoi I need the some information on the picture, to create custom widgets

Comment: updated the answer to suggest the `selectRelatedObject` flag

Comment: Unrelated, but please note that Zabbix 1.8 is very old and is not supported anymore.